# Generic model creation based on dynamic input dataset in python

Tags: python, machine-learning

I'm trying to create a generic platform where based on dataset uploaded, i need to find which machine learning algorithm will be suited for this data. I get only the target variable and parameter values required for prediction as input from UI. Can anyone tell me how to find the algorithm dynamically based on dataset.

Answer (score 0):

If you use sklearn:

you have to iterate all the models you want and find the best one best on output.

```
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_classifier_comparison.html
```

for each model, you can grid search best parameter to turn the model

```
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html
```

Comment: From the plot classifier, how to choose the best suited classification algorithm for the dataset. Also, Can you let me know for Regression algorithms too?

Comment: @SyamalaReddy you need to compare all the models you have. basic iterate all the model and pass the dataset, then compare the results

Comment: In some other post, i saw iterating all the models for the dataset and finding the mean. And the highest mean algorithm is chosen as the best algorithm. Is it the correct approach?

Comment: @SyamalaReddy it depends on which score you will use.  for sklearn: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html

Comment: It used cross-validation score. So, is it the same approach for regression also? Or we use only Linear regression for all continuous values?

Comment: @SyamalaReddy cross validation is a method the test all the models. it is not a score for prediction.  yes, you could apply this model selection method to any model